# onlocationchanged not called

Tags: android, gps

When I test the application using the Eclipse DDMS - it works, onlocationchanged called
but when I install the app on your tablet - nothing

my source

```
public class Fragment_1 extends Fragment{


      final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
      private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
        private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds
        private String bestProvider;
        private Context contextActivity;
        private LocationManager locationManager;
        private MyLocationListener locationListener;


      public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        contextActivity = getActivity(); 

        locationManager = (LocationManager)  contextActivity.getSystemService(contextActivity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria crit = new Criteria();
        crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(crit, false);
        locationListener = MyLocationListener.createMyLocationListener(this);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(

                        bestProvider,

                        MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,

                        MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,

                        locationListener);



      }
```

and my class MyLocationListener

```
ublic class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    private Fragment_1 fragment;
    private static MyLocationListener myLocationListener;

    public MyLocationListener(Fragment_1 fragment_1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        fragment  = fragment_1;

    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(fragment.getActivity() !=null) {
        TextView textViev = (TextView)fragment.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            String message = String.format(
                    "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
            );
              textViev.setText(message);}
        }


    public static MyLocationListener createMyLocationListener (Fragment_1 fragment_1) {

        if (myLocationListener == null) {

            myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener(fragment_1);
        } else {

            myLocationListener.setFragment(fragment_1);
        }

        return myLocationListener;


    }
    private void setFragment (Fragment_1 fragment){

        this.fragment = fragment;

    }

}
```

and permission in the manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```